# why default function declaration inside document ready does't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function that is declared inside document.ready() by onclick event. 
test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function change(){
       $('#content').html("changed");
   }
});
```

but it works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    change = function(){
        $('#content').html("changed");
    }
});
```

test.html

```
<div id="click" onclick="change()">click</div>
<div id="content">content</div>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

I want to know why the first declaration doesn't work but the second one works?

Comment: Because `change` is a global variable in second code.

Comment: just a thought why not use event handlers?

Comment: your document ready usage is completely pointless in that scenario. One, you're not targeting the dom inside of it, instead you're declaring a function that has to be on the global scope, and secondly your script is after the element affected so even if you switched to proper event binding it still wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Function declarations create locally scoped variables.

Assignments to previously undeclared variables create globals (except in strict mode, in which case they are errors).

If you want to call a function from a click event, then bind it using JavaScript (since you are using jQuery, use the `on` method). Avoid intrinsic event attributes in HTML.

Comment: I just wanted to know why it's happening. thanks everybody